# How do I position a UIView at the centre of two other UIViews with Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UIView in the middle of two other UIViews. Say they're called "Top", "Middle", and "Bottom". "Top" and "Bottom" are both position 20pt from the top and bottom respectively. How do I position "Middle" vertically between "Top" and "Bottom", so no matter if it's a 4" or a 3.5" device, it will always be in the middle of the two other UIViews?

Comment: What you do so far in coding?? Share your code.

Comment: I have two views. This is a question on how to do something that I have no idea is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a hidden spacer view.  (Hidden views still participate in layout.)

Constrain the top edge of the spacer to the bottom edge of Top.  Constraint the bottom edge of the spacer to the top edge of Bottom.  The width and horizontal position of the spacer don't matter, so just set them up in whatever way is convenient for you.

Then constrain the Y center of Middle to the Y center of the spacer.

Note that you **don't** need to make Middle a subview of the spacer, and you don't need to connect any outlets to the spacer.

Comment: Damn that was brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[viewMiddle setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

where

```
float y = viewTop.frame.origin.y + viewTop.frame.size.height + ((viewBottom.frame.origin.y - viewTop.frame.origin.y - viewTop.frame.size.height)/2) - (viewMiddle.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: Is this possible using Auto Layout? Frames are kind of discouraged now a days.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question

Comment: No you didn't, I edited it into the title after I realized I wasn't being specific enough. My fault. :)